# How to increase contrast with only a top entry specimen holder

Tags: microscopy

My question is: If my microscope had a top entry specimen holder, instead of a side entry holder, what additional option(s) should I have to increase the contrast with the same constraint that I only have a single objective aperture? Why would this option work?

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is a top entry specimen holder? What kind microscope is it?

Comment: If your doing EM you can ignore, out of my area of know how :-(